# How to speed up a loop-like function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, optimization

In trying to avoid using the for loop in R, I wrote a function that returns an average value from one data frame given row-specific values from another data frame. I then pass this function to sapply over the range of row numbers. My function works, but it returns ~ 2.5 results per second, which is not much better than using a for loop. So, I feel like I've not fully exploited the vectorized aspects of the apply family of functions. Can anyone help me rethink my approach? Here is a minimally working example. Thanks in advance.

```
#Creating first dataframe
dates<-seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2016-07-01"), by = 1)
n<-length(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2016-07-01"), by = 1))
df1<-data.frame(date = dates, 
             hour = sample(1:24, n,replace = T), 
             cat = sample(c("a", "b"), n, replace = T),
             lag = sample(1:24, n, replace = T))

#Creating second dataframe
df2<-data.frame(date = sort(rep(dates, 24)), 
                hour = rep(1:24, length(dates)), 
                p = runif(length(rep(dates, 24)), min = -20, max = 100))

df2<-df2[order(df2$date, df2$hour),]

df2$cat<-"a"
temp<-df2
temp$cat<-"b"
df2<-rbind(df2,temp)

#function
period_mean<-function(x){

    tmp<-df2[df$cat == df1[x,]$cat,]

    #This line extracts the row name index from tmp,
    #in which the two dataframes match on date and hour
    he_i<-which(tmp$date == df1[x,]$date & tmp$hour == df1[x,]$hour)

    #My lagged period is given by the variable "lag". I want the average
    #over the period hour - (hour - lag). Since df2 is sorted such hours  
    #are consecutive, this method requires that I subset on only the 
    #relevant value for cat (hence the creation of tmp in the first line 
    #of the function
    p<-mean(tmp[(he_i - df1[x,]$lag):he_i,]$p)

    print(x)
    print(p)
    return(p)
}

#Execute function
out<-sapply(1:length(row.names(df1)), period_mean)
```

**EDIT** I have subsequently learned that part of the reason my original problem was iterating so slowly is that my data classes between the two dataframes were not the same. df1$date was a date field, while df2$date was a character field. Of course, this wasn't apparent with the example I posted because the data types were the same by construction. Hope this helps.

Comment: It should read as follows. 
tmp<-df2[df$cat == df1[x,]$cat,]

I've edited the original post. Good catch!

Comment: There are several other `df`s in your function, do you mean `df1` in all these cases?

Comment: I did mean df1. I have edited the original post again. Sorry for the typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one suggestion:

```
getIdx <- function(i) {
    date <- df1$date[i]
    hour <- df1$hour[i]    
    cat <- df1$cat[i]
    which(df2$date==date & df2$hour==hour & df2$cat==cat)
}
v_getIdx <- Vectorize(getIdx)

df1$index <- v_getIdx(1:nrow(df1))
b_start <- match("b", df2$cat)
out2 <- apply(df1[,c("cat","lag","index")], MAR=1, function(x) {
    flr <- ifelse(x[1]=="a", 1, b_start)
    x <- as.numeric(x[2:3])
    mean(df2$p[max(flr, (x[2]-x[1])):x[2]])
})
```

We make a function (`getIdx`) to retrieve the rows from `df2` that match the values from each row in `df1`, and then `Vectorize` the function.

We then run the vectorized function to get a vector of rownames.  We set `b_start` to be the row where the "b" category starts.

We then iterate through the rows of `df1` with `apply`.  In the `mean(...)` function, we set the "floor" to be either row 1 (if `cat=="a"`) or `b_start` (if `cat=="b"`), which eliminates the need to subset (what you were doing with `tmp`).

Performance:

```
> system.time(out<-sapply(1:length(row.names(df1)), period_mean))
   user  system elapsed 
 11.304   0.393  11.917 

> system.time({
+     df1$index <- v_getIdx(1:nrow(df1))
+     b_start <- match("b", df2$cat)
+     out2 <- apply(df1[,c("cat","lag","index")], MAR=1, function(x) {
+         flr <- ifelse(x[1]=="a", 1, b_start)
+         x <- as.numeric(x[2:3])
+         mean(df2$p[max(flr, (x[2]-x[1])):x[2]])
+     })
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  2.839   0.405   3.274 

> all.equal(out, out2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Weihuang Wong! I'll test this approach.

Comment: This works beautifully for my application.  I especially appreciate how you a) showed me the proper way to vectorize the function and b) demonstrate how I could restrict between my two categories appropriately. THANK YOU!